# How does one access the URL arguments in codeigniter if one was to follow REST architecture?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

The following is a valid REST based URL that can be used to access a resource:

Using codeigniter, how can one access the parameter of 1 that was passed below.

[image]

I saw the above in a tutorial and have set up my code. However obviously:

```
 $id = $this->input->get('id');
```

does not work.

Comment: Just FYI, REST has no opinion on the style of your URI and query parameters are just as significant as path segments for resource identification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `$this->input->get('id')` would suggest you are sending ?id=1 to the end of the URL. You can use `$this->uri->segment(1)` but that does not allow for paired uri segments.

If you use `$this->get('id')` which is a special REST_Controller method then it will pick up either. I did put that in the tutorial you got this image from :)

Comment: thanks Phil. You rock man.I am using your REST controller. You back from vacation?

Answer (score 3):

From the [URI Class.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

you can use `$this->uri->segment(n)`

Where n is the segment number you wish to retrieve .